# Ruby String manipulation of HTML Element IDs

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a safe way of building a string of a HTML element id from another element id.

I need to go from something like "attr_name_442_a" to "attr-row-422", the text part of the ids are consistent with just the number changing. This number will be in the range of 1 to 4 digits.

I thought of doing this but is there a better Ruby style method?

```
newID = oldID.gsub("_","-").gsub("name","row").gsub("-a","")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to pull this off with a single Regex

```
newID = oldID.gsub /(\w+)_name_(\d+)_a/, '\1-row-\2'
```

Comment: BTW, are you [that guy with all those cats](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHXBL6bzAR4)?

Comment: No but I saw that video and empathized with the guy instantly :) Which reminds me.. My profile needs an update. Down to just two cats now.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_id = "#$1-row-#$2" if $old_id =~ /\A([^_]+)_name_(\d{1,4})_a\z/
```

I would probably add an `else` condition if the regex didn't match just so I knew I was catching everything.